# VSC Apex-prettier-plugin-apex doesn't format - throws error

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, apex-code, prettier, npx

I use Visual Studio Code and have installed Prettier plugin as well as Prettier-plugin-apex according to https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/prettier
(also https://www.sfdcnotes.com/2019/12/16/vs-code-extension-prettier-code-formatter/).

It used to format my classes but lately has been failing, but all I see is this in the bottom right with no explanation of what's wrong when I save a class file (it does format on save/deploy on save).

[image]

When I try and manually format with `npx prettier --write` I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev> npx prettier --write force- 
app/main/default/classes/emailReportController_Test.cls     
force-app\main\default\classes\emailReportController_Test.cls
[error] force-app\main\default\classes\emailReportController_Test.cls: Error
[error]     at parseTextWithSpawn  (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\src\parser.js:36:11)
[error]     at Object.parse (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\src\parser.js:489:21)
[error]     at Object.parse$a [as parse] (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\index.js:14892:19)
[error]     at coreFormat (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\index.js:16425:16)
[error]     at formatWithCursor$1 (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\index.js:16665:14)
[error]     at Object.formatWithCursor (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\index.js:60922:12)
[error]     at format$1 (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\bin-prettier.js:16107:14)
[error]     at Object.formatFiles$1 [as formatFiles] (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\bin-prettier.js:16218:16)
[error]     at main (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\bin-prettier.js:17989:10)
[error]     at Object.run (C:\Users\xx\Documents\VSC\SynDev\node_modules\prettier\bin-prettier.js:17932:5)
```

How do I fix this - what is wrong (I'm no expert on VSC or npm)?

This is my *package.json* file:

```
{
  "name": "salesforce-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Salesforce App",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npm run lint:lwc && npm run lint:aura",
    "lint:aura": "eslint **/aura/**",
    "lint:lwc": "eslint **/lwc/**",
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
    "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch",
    "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
    "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\"",
    "prettier:verify": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prettier/plugin-xml": "^0.12.0",
    "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc": "^0.11.0",
    "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-aura": "^2.0.0",
    "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.10.4",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.7",
    "prettier": "2.3.0",
    "prettier-plugin-apex": "1.9.1"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "**/{aura|lwc}/**": [
      "eslint"
    ]
  },
  "main": "jest.config.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And *.prettierrc*

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "**/lwc/**/*.html",
      "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
    },
    {
      "files": "*.{cmp,page,component}",
      "options": { "parser": "html" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and found a workaround.

Install a previous version of `prettier-plugin-apex` by changing the version number in `package.json`:

`"prettier-plugin-apex": "1.8.0"`

Edit:
Then run `npm install prettier-plugin-apex` to actually perform the downgrade.

Comment: That worked in my dev environment, thanks, although the newer version will surely need to be used at some point. I also had to run 'npm install prettier-plugin-apex' after editing the package.json file.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, glad that it worked! You are right, I took for granted that a `npm install` was required, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I had to upgrade JDK from 8 to 11 to fix this.